# Accessing views variables in page.tpl.php

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system

how to access views variables in page.tpl.php or node.tpl.php

Comment: You'll need to elaborate a bit there, mate.

Comment: Get current view? - http://api.lullabot.com/views_get_current_view

Comment: This question has been downvoted and voted to close as "not a real question" by 2 users. I beg to disagree with such a harsh reaction: the question is very clear and accessing view variables outside the view's template is an interesting thing to ask about. @MJH: an upvote from me for asking that.

Answer (score 3):

In your theme_preprocess function in template.php, you can use the [views_get_current_view()](http://api.lullabot.com/views_get_current_view) function to access any views data for the view that you are loading.  The $variables are pass by reference, so you can add and manipulate them as necessary.  More information is located in [Setting up variables for use in a template](http://drupal.org/node/223430) documentation on Drupal's website.

Comment: first link is dead. Try this one: https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_current_view/7